# How to convert a function call into a MethodCallExpression

Tags: c#

I'm trying to facilitate the use of my library for my users.

I have an Interface I, and a class A ...

```
public interface I
{
    int f(int i);
}

public class A : I
{
   public int f(int i)
   {
      return i * i;
   }
}
```

I'm trying to write a function Call that take a call to f and makes operations.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    I obj = new A();

    Call(obj.f(3));
}
```

But I don't know how to get the function into the "Call" function. My aim is that call is generic and will work with all types !
So I try with `MethodCallExpression` but I don't really know how to convert obj.f(3) into a `MethodCallExpression` ....

```
public void Call(MethodCallExpression expr)
{

}
```

Thank you very much for any help :)

Comment: Huh? What are you trying to do?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776442/how-to-call-the-method-from-a-methodcallexpression-in-c

Comment: I want to execute the code obj.f(3) (which will turn in a different thread) and return a Func<int>. typically : var x = Call(obj.f(3)); and then Console.Out(x());.

Comment: A does not implement I as the method f is not public

Comment: You're still very unclear.  Please provide a complete example.

Comment: Sorry ^^ I'm trying to simplify my problem. I'm coding a computing grid. It works well, but my API is not really simple and logical. For the moment, the user do : obj.f(3); and obj.getResult(); getResult blocks the program and wait for a result. I want to avoid the call to getResult and provide a more user friendly API.

Comment: And the call to f() and getResult() are catch by Castle ActiveRecord.

Comment: @Ben Robinson: This is about C#.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    I obj = new A();
    Func<A,int> expression = (a => a.f(3))
    Call<A>(expression, obj);
}

public void Call<T>(MethodCallExpression expr, T data)
{
    expr(data);
}
```

Comment: Yes it can be a first solution ! But if there is a way to pass a function to Call and to not evaluate it immediately, it will be better :)

Comment: I changed it to show how you can evaluate the expression inside of the Call function.

Comment: It does not seem that Func<A, int> can be cast to MethodCallExpression. It comes out as InvocationExpression