# Invoke an instance method from a expression

Tags: c#, expression

I am trying to sort out how I can invoke an instance method described in a Expression> with the arguments provided to the method.

There's a similar question here: [How to call the method from a MethodCallExpression in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776442/how-to-call-the-method-from-a-methodcallexpression-in-c-sharp), but it operates under the context of a non-instance method. My question is: how do I build up the expression with the appropriate instance before invoking it.

```
void Main()
{
    Expression<Action<MyClass>> expr = x => x.SomeMethod("Nathan", 10, 1.5d); 

    // i need to provide the expression a new MyClass()

    Expression.Lambda(expr).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
}

public class MyClass 
{
    public void SomeMethod(string param1, int param2, double param3) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello: {0}, {1}, {2}", param1, param2, param3);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question? It seems like it has to be how to do what you said in the comment ("i need to provide the expression a new MyClass()"), but what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: @31eee384 I feel like the last paragraph of my question made clear that I was unsure how to populate the Action<T> with an instance. That said, I have rephrased, hopefully to your liking...

Comment: Ah, I guess being "unsure" about something doesn't sound like an answerable question to me. I'd suggest using question marks: they make it clear where the question is and force the sentence to sound like a question. I'm still not sure what "build up" means, though. (And just in case you thought so, I am not downvoter. So feel free to ignore me if the answer works for you--everything worked out fine.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to call the expression, you need to compile it to delegate and then call it:

```
Expression<Action<MyClass>> expr = x => x.SomeMethod("Nathan", 10, 1.5d); 
Action<MyClass> action = expr.Compile();

MyClass instance = new MyClass();
action(instance);
```

Comment: Blah! This is so obvious. Thank you. The question I referenced originally took me entirely in the wrong direction.

Comment: @NathanTaylor But, does my answer *answer* your issue? :O

Comment: @NathanTaylor Well, I asked you this because I was unsure if you required further details ;P BTW, who knows why someone downvoted my answer...